# Error while trying to cleanup Cassandra node

Tags: cassandra

I am facing issue while launching cleanup command with nodetool.

Cleanup did work fine until now. I did'nt find any modification on my configuration. I have no clue on what could have change.

```
nodetool > cleanup
error: Expecting URI in variable: [cassandra.config]. Found[cassandra.yaml]. Please prefix the file with [file:///] for local files and [file://<server>/] for remote files. If you are executing this from an external tool, it needs to set Config.setClientMode(true) to avoid loading configuration.
-- StackTrace --
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Expecting URI in variable: [cassandra.config]. Found[cassandra.yaml]. Please prefix the file with [file:///] for local files and [file://<server>/] for remote files. If you are executing this from an external tool, it needs to set Config.setClientMode(true) to avoid loading configuration.
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.getStorageConfigURL(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:80)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:100)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:262)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.toolInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:180)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.toolInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:151)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeProbe.checkJobs(NodeProbe.java:281)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeProbe.forceKeyspaceCleanup(NodeProbe.java:288)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.nodetool.Cleanup.execute(Cleanup.java:55)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool$NodeToolCmd.run(NodeTool.java:255)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.main(NodeTool.java:169)
```

Any idea ?

Regards,

Nicolas

Comment: Is the actual command you issued: "nodetool > cleanup"? If so, that wouldn't work. Unless I'm misunderstanding your pasted text.

Comment: What version of cassandra?

Comment: Hi guys, I'm running Cassandra 3.11.3-1 , and the actual command is really that one. Why wouldn't it works ? I used it as this many time without issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find a solution that works for me (but i think it's specific to my prod environment).

Somewhere, something should have used /etc/alternative/cassandra symlink, which was heading to my empty default cassandra configuration.
After i correct it :

```
[root@myhost ~]# ll /etc/alternatives/
total 116
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Oct  2 12:40 cassandra -> /etc/cassandra/my-cassandra-instance
```

That done, i was able to cleanup my cassandra clusters.

Didn't find time to work this case much more.

Anyway thanks for the clues, it was a context issue.

Nicolas

Answer (score 1):

Nodetool uses cassandra.yaml to to find the number of concurrent compactors. Since you have `cassandra.config` set its using that cassandra.yaml, but the `cassandra.config` has an invalid value so the nodetool is choking on it.

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for this lead. Any idea how i can change this cassandra.config value ?

Comment: You could always override it in the `nodetool` script (`-Dcassandra.config=file:///path/cassandra.yaml`) but might be worth trying to track down whats wrong in your environment thats causing it to be wrong. How did you install it? Can you use normal packages?